# VS Code debugging in electron-forge

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, electron-forge

I set up my electron-forge project using TypeScript and React (as shown in their instructions), and I want to set up the VS code debugger for my app. I used the launch config provided by electron-forge [here](https://www.electronforge.io/advanced/debugging):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Electron Main",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron-forge-vscode-nix",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron-forge-vscode-win.cmd"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run this debug configuration, an electron window opens, but it uses the directory name (not same as the title in the `<title>` tag in my HTML) and my react components don't render. It also never reaches any breakpoints (I set one on the call to `ReactDOM.render()` but the code never reached it). However, when I just run `yarn start`, my code runs properly.

Trying to get the vscode debugger to launch the app using the yarn script and attach the debugger did not work either.

Any help is appreciated on trying to get the debugger to work.

UPDATE: now no window opens at all...